# Restream files from another server to client springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stream, resttemplate

I have 2 services - Ingress (input node) and Storage.
Client send requests on Ingress to get some data (large files).
Ingress send request to Storage to get data that Client needs.
Maybe, somebody can tell what I can use to restream response from Storage to Client without OutOfMemory issues.

Now I've implemented it as saving result in file on Ingress, rereading it and sending as response to Client. But it works really slow, of course.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway) (more documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/)) can help. It's primary purpose seems to be as a configuration-driven gateway, but it can be embedded into an application to serve just certain endpoints; so you may be able to configure it in your "Ingress" service to route certain requests to your Storage service.

If that doesn't work (or, as was in my case, it's too much work), you can use some specific classes from Spring Cloud Gateway in your own service. Specifically, I've used the `ProxyExchange` class to [proxy calls to another service](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__building_a_simple_gateway_using_spring_mvc.html) and stream the results back to the original caller.